# The "fill" label does not work properly after combining some plots with subplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, subplot

I have this data frame:

```
gene_symbol<-c("DADA","SDAASD","SADDSD","SDADD","ASDAD","XCVXCVX","EQWESDA","DASDADS","SDASDASD","DADADASD","sdaadfd","DFSD","SADADDAD","SADDADADA","DADSADSASDWQ","SDADASDAD","ASD","DSADD")
panel<-c("growth","growth","growth","growth","big","big","big","small","small","small","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDA<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDb<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf2<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf3<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf4<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf5<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDA1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDb1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf11<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf21<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf31<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf41<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf51<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
Gene_states22<-data.frame(gene_symbol,panel,ASDDA,ASDDb,ASDDAf,ASDDAf1,ASDDAf2,ASDDAf3,ASDDAf4,ASDDAf5,ASDDA1,ASDDb1,ASDDAf1,ASDDAf11,ASDDAf21,ASDDAf31,ASDDAf41,ASDDAf51)
```

Then I create 4 heatmaps based on the number of diffrenet panel types.

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2); library(reshape2)
HG3<-split(Gene_states22[,1:15], Gene_states22$panel)
HG4 <- melt(HG3, id.vars= c("gene_symbol","panel"))
HG4<-HG4[,-5]
HG5<-split(HG4, HG4$panel)
p<-list()

p[[1]]<-ggplotly(
  ggplot(HG5[[1]], aes(gene_symbol,variable)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value),
                                                          colour = "grey50") + scale_fill_manual(values=c("white", "red", "blue","black","yellow","green","brown"))+
    labs(title = "Heatmap",x = "gene_symbol",y="sample",fill="value")+
    guides(fill=FALSE)+
    theme(title = element_text(family = "sans serif", 
                               size = 14, 
                               face = "bold"), 
          axis.title = element_text(family = "sans serif", 
                                    size = 16, 
                                    face = "bold", 
                                    color = "black"), 
          axis.text.x = element_text(family = "sans serif", 
                                     size = 11),
          axis.text.y= element_text(family = "sans serif", 
                                    size = 11),
          axis.title.y = element_text(vjust = 10,hjust = 10),
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
          panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey50"),
          panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
          strip.placement = "outside")
)%>%
  layout( autosize = F,hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "white",
                                         font = list(family = "sans serif", 
                                                     size = 9, 
                                                     color = "black"))) 
for(i in 2:as.numeric(length(HG5)-1)){


  p[[i]]<-ggplotly(
    ggplot(HG5[[i]], aes(gene_symbol,variable)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value),
                                                            colour = "grey50") + scale_fill_manual(values=c("white", "red", "blue","black","yellow","green","brown"))+
      labs(title = "Heatmap",x = "gene_symbol",y="sample",fill="value")+
      guides(fill=FALSE)+
      theme(title = element_text(family = "sans serif", 
                                 size = 14, 
                                 face = "bold"), 
            axis.title = element_text(family = "sans serif", 
                                      size = 16, 
                                      face = "bold", 
                                      color = "black"), 
            axis.text.x = element_text(family = "sans serif", 
                                       size = 11),
            axis.title.y = element_blank(),
            axis.text.y=element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
            panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey50"),
            panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
            strip.placement = "outside")
  )%>%
    layout( autosize = F,hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "white",
                                           font = list(family = "sans serif", 
                                                       size = 9, 
                                                       color = "black")))
}
for(i in as.numeric(length(HG5):as.numeric(length(HG5)))){


  p[[i]]<-ggplotly(
    ggplot(HG5[[i]], aes(gene_symbol,variable)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value),
                                                            colour = "grey50") + scale_fill_manual(values=c("white", "red", "blue","black","yellow","green","brown"))+
      labs(title = "Heatmap",x = "gene_symbol",y="sample",fill="value")+
      theme(title = element_text(family = "sans serif", 
                                 size = 14, 
                                 face = "bold"), 
            axis.title = element_text(family = "sans serif", 
                                      size = 16, 
                                      face = "bold", 
                                      color = "black"), 
            axis.text.x = element_text(family = "sans serif", 
                                       size = 10),
            axis.title.y = element_blank(),
            axis.text.y=element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
            panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey50"),
            panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
            strip.placement = "outside")
  )%>%
    layout( autosize = F,width=1350,height=600,hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "white",
                                                                 font = list(family = "sans serif", 
                                                                             size = 9, 
                                                                             color = "black")))
}
```

Then I combine them with subplot

```
subplot(p)%>% layout(yaxis = list(title = "sample"),xaxis=list(title="gene_symbol"),margin = list(l = 200, b = -10, t =-10))
```

The problem is that I want the value label to be displayed only once after the last plot but as you can see in the picture it displays the values in a quite strange way. Normally it should display only "low","normal","over","DF". What I tried to do is hide the value labels from the first three heatmaps with `guides(fill=FALSE)` and display only the last heatmap value label.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens with plotly. It brings back the legend. Not simple, but you could you get rid of the legend with this:

```
for (i in 1:39){
  p[[2]]$x$data[[i]]$showlegend <- FALSE
}


for (i in 1:39){
  p[[3]]$x$data[[i]]$showlegend <- FALSE
}

for (i in 1:39){
  p[[4]]$x$data[[i]]$showlegend <- FALSE
}

subplot(p) %>% layout(yaxis = list(title = "sample"),xaxis=list(title="gene_symbol"),margin = list(l = 200, b = -10, t =-10))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks ! that is an exceptional answer. I have 2 more questions about moving the x-title in the middle of the subplot and also give a unique subtitle to each one of the heatmaps but I will create a new topic I guess.